# replace two consecutive lines based on a pattern and repeat through out the file

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace two consecutive lines based on a pattern match, and would want this to repeat for the entire file. Here is the input file:

```
c aaaaa bbb
+ 0.1
c xxxx
c yyyy
+ 0.2
* c gggg
m eeeee hhhhh
+ 0.3
```

The command I tried is:

```
sed '/^c/{N;s/+/*+/}'
```

I expected to see a `*` prepended to each line beginning, but only those lines immediatlely following a `c` line:

```
c aaaaa bbb
*+ 0.1
c xxxx
c yyyy
*+ 0.2
* c gggg
m eeeee hhhhh
+ 0.3
```

what I actually get:

```
c aaaaa bbb
*+ 0.1
c xxxx
c yyyy
+ 0.2
* c gggg
m eeeee hhhhh
+ 0.3
```

Here, i see only the first occurrence of `+` (with previous line beginning with c) is getting replaced with `*+`. The second occurrence of `+` in the file is not getting replaced.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get the result I want: replacement happens in multiple consecutive lines in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you run into is that when a line that starts with `c` comes right after another line that comes with `c`, the `N` command in your code consumes it, and it isn't available for checking when you process the line that comes next.

Instead of reading ahead to see if the next line should be changed, I'd remember the last line and look back to see if the current line should be changed:

```
sed 'x; G; /^c/ s/+/*+/; s/.*\n//' file
```

This works as follows:

```
x                # Swap pattern space and hold buffer. Because we do this here,
                 # the previous line will be in the hold buffer for every line
                 # (except the first, then it is empty)

G                # append hold buffer to pattern space. Now the pattern space
                 # contains the previous line followed by the current line.

/^c/ s/+/*+/     # If the pattern space begins with a c (i.e., if the previous
                 # line began with a c), replace + with *+

s/.*\n//         # Remove the first line (the previous one) from the pattern
                 # space

                 # Then drop off the end. The changed current line is printed.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 'H;$!d' -e 'x' -e ':cycle' -e 's/\(\nc[[:alnum:][:blank:][:punct:]]*\n\)+/\1*+/g;t cycle' -e 's/.//' YourFile
```

Posix version changing the whoe in max 2 internal cycle

- load the file in memory (`-e 'H;$!d' -e 'x'`)
- Add the * in front of line starting with a `+` after a line starting with a `c`  ( `s/\(\nc[[:alnum:][:blank:][:punct:]]*\n\)+/\1*+/g`)
- do the same if occur in previous line ( `:cycle` and `t cycle`)
- use a trick to insure starting with new line( `H` append current line to buffer also for first line so an extra new line as heading) (for first line with a `c`) and remove this at the end (`'s/.//`)